# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'. > Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to import a android studio projext, and i find this error

[image: example image]

this is the error text

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "$USE_DEPRECATED_NDK=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create the file **gradle.properties** with the content `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` for this error.

Also make sure that you have installed the NDK. You should provide the path of the NDK directory to **local.properties** file as `ndk.dir=PutYourNdkPath`.